# Migrate Vue.js to Angular 6. Tips are welcome?

Tags: vue.js, angular6, ng-upgrade, angular-upgrade

Need to migrate from vue.js to Angular 6. Is there a better approach to start with and need best practices too as new to both the frameworks.

Comment: I believe this question is too wide an opinionated for stack overflow. I bet you will find more help in forums like https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/angular or in more wide Q/A sites like quora. That said, vue and Angular share some syntax, but nothing more that allows you for a direct migration. Unless your vue app is really well architected and services and logic modules are abstracted out, I'm afraid you'll have to redo and dirty copypaste a lot of work.

Comment: @Sergeon: Thanks a lot for the answer. Yes, I need to do copy paste and do from scratch. Started in such a way only; Looking at how to write components and more ways to architect the same, in order to have an easy and smooth step.